# Fancybox AJAX feature explanation

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

```
 case 'ajax':
                busy = false;

                $.fancybox.showActivity();

                selectedOpts.ajax.win = selectedOpts.ajax.success;

                ajaxLoader = $.ajax($.extend({}, selectedOpts.ajax, {
                    url : href,
                    data : selectedOpts.ajax.data || {},
                    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if ( XMLHttpRequest.status > 0 ) {
                            _error();
                        }
                    },
                    success : function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        var o = typeof XMLHttpRequest == 'object' ? XMLHttpRequest : ajaxLoader;
                        if (o.status == 200) {
                            if ( typeof selectedOpts.ajax.win == 'function' ) {
                                ret = selectedOpts.ajax.win(href, data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest);

                                if (ret === false) {
                                    loading.hide();
                                    return;
                                } else if (typeof ret == 'string' || typeof ret == 'object') {
                                    data = ret;
                                }
                            }

                            tmp.html( data );
                            _process_inline();
                        }
                    }
                }));

            break;
```

I don't understand why

```
 selectedOpts.ajax.win = selectedOpts.ajax.success;
```

has been initialized like this where the success has been initialized?
where the

```
         selectedOpts.ajax.data
```

has been initialized?

where the call is transferred in this statement

```
          ret = selectedOpts.ajax.win(href, data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest);
```

where is the method body?

Comment: No idea. Have you tried searching your source for `selectedOpts`?

Comment: yes. every nook and cranny but no help. selectedOpts = $.extend({}, $.fn.fancybox.defaults, (typeof $(obj).data('fancybox') == 'undefined' ? selectedOpts : $(obj).data('fancybox')));   This statement initializes the SelectedOpts but neither Default nor fancybox data has any evidence of its initialization

Comment: Are you simply curious or do you have a specific issue with fancybox?

Comment: I am studying fancybox to understand jquery in more detail and actually wanted to create similar functionalty plus added functionality for studentjoin.com. I am exhausted am studying this plugin for 1 week.

Comment: You may have an easier time learning jQuery from [one of the many tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are unaware of jquery ajax.

selectedOpts.ajax.win(href, data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest); is basically jquery ajax success function. You have to override success function and these variables are passed by jquery ajax.

Data is set using jquery extend. You have to pass your ajax variable.

**UPDATE** (moved commented code into the answer)

```
$("#Link").fancybox({ 
 ajax : { 
  type : "POST", 
  data : 'mydata=test', 
  success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
   // do something on success
  } 
 } 
});
```

Comment: Oh Yaar. I understand what are they. But where is the overridden function of SelectedOpts.ajax.win(). Data is using extend.. Where?

Comment: its basically jquery ajax success function 
selectedOpts.ajax.win = selectedOpts.ajax.success;
Here you see jquery ajax success function is using as selectedOpts.ajax.win

Comment: but the ajax={} is defined in the Defaults. And nothing about the ajax.success is defined. so how SelectedOpts.ajax.Success references the Success of $.Ajax().

Comment: yes in default its emtpty. If you provide ajax option default will be overrided.
if you don't provide the ajax options nothing get assigned to selectedOpts.ajax.win and this if condiction returns false. because this will be null
if ( typeof selectedOpts.ajax.win == 'function' ) {
}

Comment: ok.. slightly makes sense. but where is the SelectedOpts.ajax.success overridden. selectedOpts.ajax.win = selectedOpts.ajax.success. Does not makes sense to me. They both (win, success) seems uninitialized. assigning one uninitialized to another? am I right?

Comment: you have to override this if you need success function for you ajax request. when you are initializing the fancybox. SelectedOpts.ajax.success 

Yes if you don't set this it is uninitialized. and assigned to other

Comment: ok. Now clear. Thanks. any example of how to do it in fancybox initialization.

Comment: $("#Link").fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : 'mydata=test',
  success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  
  }
    }
});

I am assuming you accept this as answer

Comment: definitely . Thank you my friend. You saved me another week.